# Send google forms responses to google calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have recently began a project to allow communication between separate groups of people to confirm appointments for meetings. The problem is I can't seem to be able to send the response from a form to the google calendar ID that I put in the function.

Could somebody explain what is going wrong with the code or lead me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
//Function records responses and sends them to a google calendar.

function onFormSubmit(e) {

    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); // opens active form

    var usarResponses = form.getResponses(); // collects responses

    //Loop creates an array for responses
    for(var i = 0; i < usarResponses.length; i++){
    var usarResponse = usarResponses[i];
    }

    //responses are put into variables.

    var name = usarResponses[0];
    var appointmentName = usarResponses[1];
    var appointmentDate = usarResponses[2];
    var uDescription = usarResponses[3];


    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('kq14it8fl42i560gl6ueeo4qu8@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(appointmentName, new Date(appointmentDate), new Date('8:00:00  UTC') , {description: uDescription});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. Here is what worked for me:

```
function createEvent() {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
var responses = form.getResponses();
var len = responses.length;
var last = len – 1;
var items = responses[last].getItemResponses();
var email = responses[last].getRespondentEmail();
var name = items[0].getResponse();
var bring = items[1].getResponse();
var date = items[2].getResponse();
Logger.log(date);
var replace = date.replace(/-/g,”/”);
Logger.log(replace);
var start = new Date(replace);
Logger.log(‘start ‘+start);

//Logger.log(newStart.getHours());
var endHours = 2+0+start.getHours();//2 hour event

//Logger.log(start.getDay());
var day = start.getDate();
var minutes = start.getMinutes();
var year = start.getFullYear();
var month = start.getMonth();
var hours = start.getHours();

var d = new Date(year, month, day, endHours, minutes);
Logger.log(d);

var event = cal.createEvent(‘Class Party ‘+name+’ brings ‘+bring, start, d)
.addGuest(email)
.setDescription(name+’ you will be bringing ‘+bring+’ to the party.’);

GmailApp.sendEmail(email, name+’ a Google Calendar invite has been created for you’, name+’ You filled out the Google Form for the date of ‘+start+’. Check your Google Calendar to confirm that you received the invite.\n’);

}
```